# How to calculate state population from MCTDH?

Tags: quantum-dynamics, mctdh

In [this reference](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.0c00455), the author investigates electronic population dynamics from a MCTDH calculation. My question is how to generate state populations over time from an MCTDH calculation? Is there a formula for that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part of the paper where they give the formula for the populations is here:

> "The timedependent (TD) vibronic wavefunction of the system is computed solving the TD Schroedinger Equation. It is written as $|\Psi_i(\mathbf{q},t)\rangle  = \sum_i |d_i\rangle |\Psi(\mathbf{q},t)\rangle$ so that electronic populations are simply $P_i(t) =  \langle \Psi_i (\mathbf{q},t) |  \Psi_i (\mathbf{q},t) \rangle$."

Basically you propagate the wavefunctions for each state labeled by $i$ using MCTDH, and then do the inner products $\langle \psi_i | \psi_i \rangle$ for each $i$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask the state population here is adiabatic state or diabatic state?

Comment: I closed the paper, but if I recall correctly, the $d_i$ were diabatic states.